# Problem importing data from Excel to Treeview

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter, treeview

I created a treeview to display the data imported from an excel file.

```
    def afficher():
        fichier = r"*.xlsx"
        df = pd.read_excel(fichier)
        for row in df:
            refOF = row['refOF']
            refP = row['refP']
            refC = row['refC']
            nbreP = row['nbreP']
            dateFF = row['dateFF']
            self.ordreF.insert("", 0, values=(refOF, refP, refC, nbreP, dateFF))
```

but I encounter the following error:

```
refOF = row['refOF']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

please tell me how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the "row" in `for row in df` to see what happened? Please also consider providing sample data in a [reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391). Otherwise people won't be able to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is replacing the original for loop with the following:

```
for tup in df[['refOF', 'refP', 'refC', 'nbreP', 'dateFF']].itertuples(index=False, name=None):
    self.ordreF.insert("", 0, values=tup)
```

It works because `df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)` returns a regular tuple without index in the assigned column order. The tuple can be fed into the `values=` argument directly.

Answer (score 0):

With your loop you are actually not iterating over the rows, but over the column names. That is the reason for the error message, because `row` is the string with the colum name and if you use `[]` you need to specify an integer or an integer based slice, but not a string.
To make your code work, you would just need to modify your code a bit to iterate over the rows:

```
def afficher():
    fichier = r"*.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(fichier)
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        refOF = row['refOF']
        refP = row['refP']
        refC = row['refC']
        nbreP = row['nbreP']
        dateFF = row['dateFF']
        self.ordreF.insert("", 0, values=(refOF, refP, refC, nbreP, dateFF))
```